# Sunpy IO FITS Read unable to read from absolute path

Tags: python, path, fits

I am trying to read a fits file, but unable to. Here is my situation:

Current Working Directory: `~/cwd`

Path to file1: `/data/file1.fits` (Note the file is on `/`)

Path to file2: `~/cwd/file2.fits`

Whenever I try to read both files, I can successfully ready `file2` where as for `file1`, it throws an error:

```
>>> import sunpy
>>> sunpy.io.fits.read(file1path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/file1.fits'
>>> sunpy.io.fits.read(file2path)
(successfully read file2)
```

I believe it has to do something with file paths but I am not able to figure our the fix.

Comment: 'Note the file is on /'....so why are you trying to read it from '/data'??

Comment: I guess the file does not exist.  Are you sure you have the path right?  There's no reason you would get an error like that unless the file did not exist at that path.

Comment: @MartinJames becuase file is on that path.

Comment: @Iguananaut Yep. File is present over there.

Comment: What happens if you just run `open('/data/file1.fits')`?